# How to purchase elementary OS on the company? (No option for entering Company Name and VAT Number)

Tags: elementary-website

I am a self-employed developer who uses elementary OS in my daily work, and since I really like elementary I want to contribute economically by paying for the installation ISO. However, I have had to pay out my own pocket each time since there is no option for entering a Company Name and VAT Number in the purchase dialog. I'm probably not the only one who likes elementary and also owns a (small) company, and I guess this could affect the sales negatively if people are not willing to pay out of your own pockets.

Are there any others in a similar situation? In that case, how did you solve it? My suggestion to the elementary team is otherwise to add options for entering such details in the purchase dialog, so that I (and others in my situation) won't be put off from purchasing the installation ISOs.

Answer (score 1):

If you pay from a credit card that belongs to your company, and not you personally, maybe it's enough. Talk to an accountant about it, maybe by paying with the company's credit card, even without VAT, you can deduct the expense. Or maybe the accountant can book it as a donation, which technically it is. (I can't give you a definitive answer, bookkeeping varies from country to country.)

Answer (score 0):

No VAT or other Sales Tax is charged on the purchase and it is not legally classified as a donation. Companies should have nothing to claim back and simply using a company card should be sufficient bookkeeping. Alternatively you can purchase it personally and submit to whatever remittance procedure your company has.